# Entry name 'res/color/material_on_surface_disabled.xml' collided

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-webview

I just created a signed apk after which, I added two files to my project- my_web_activity.xml and MyWebActivity.kt. After compiling the code, I got the error-"Entry name 'res/color/material_on_surface_disabled.xml' collided" Nothing else was specified.

my_web_activity.xml

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/my_web_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MyWebActivity.kt
```
package com.albertjokelin.revise

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds

class MyWebActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var mAdView: AdView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.my_web_activity)

        // Google Ad view
        MobileAds.initialize(this)
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
        val adRequest: AdRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
    }

}
```

Edit: I ended up rebuilding the whole project from scratch after trying everything available at that time. So I don't know which solution works. Cheers!
````

Comment: did you try rebuilding project

Answer (score 24):

I have got this problem when I made an update in a splash screen and a **quick solution is**

1. Delete your **build** folder from android/app/**build** or yourProjectFoler/build
2. Delete your **release** folder from android/app/**release** or yourProjectFoler/release
3. **Last step** from android studio goto => **Build** > **Rebuild Project**

Try now! I hope it will work...

Comment: This works for me - in fact just doing "Build > Clean Project" works for me - but I have to do it every time I change devices, which is quite frequent. Definitely seems to be an issue with the build process

Comment: I agree there's serious bug in the build process.  I can now no longer EVER produce a signed APK without some `metadata collided` message that forces me to do all the steps above. As if my Android life weren't already completely miserable, apparently, generating an APK is simply no longer possible.

Answer (score 14):

Go To Build > Clean Project

Comment: This worked for me too. "Clean Project" + "Rebuild Project"

Answer (score 1):

don't delete anything just turn off android studio than turn on then make clean and rebuilt to your project and every thing will be good

Answer (score 0):

Tried INVALIDATE CACHES AND RESTART and works perfect. The main reason is android studio tries to update the build index but is not able to access it !

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `build` folder in the **project** hierarchy & the `release`/`debug` folder in the **app** hierarchy,then rebuild your project, it worked for me that way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `Build -> Clean Project` and `File -> Invalidate cache too`.

Nothing worked.

Only thing that worked for me was deleting the previous apk that was generated

Which is in `android/app/debug/app-debug.apk`